# CorePlot touch recognition scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I implement the following function and I set CPTScatterPlot `delegate` to self and `boundLinePlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` to 320.0f.

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"index %d",index);
}
```

When i touch the scatterplot graph anywhere the delegate method run correctly and return the nearest index, but the scroll don't working because the delegate method catches all taps.

how to solve this problem?

Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` setting. You've told it to register a touch anywhere within 320 pixels of a plot point. On an iPhone screen, that's pretty much the whole graph. A more typical setting would be somewhere between 5 and 15.

Comment: okay, but if i want to touch anywhere on the screen(graph) then the delegate method return the nearest point, what is the right solution?

Comment: You said you wanted to be able to scroll, too. You can't have it both ways using the built-in functionality. If you use a plot space delegate instead of a scatter plot delegate, you could process the down/drag/up events yourself and decide when to register a hit on the plot and when to scroll.